# Django Prevent Automatic Save During Object.Create

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

First off disclaimer: I'm using django-mongodb-engine it's possible the issue I'm observing is due to the different db driver. In any event, it seems that calling MyModel.object.create() actually creates a database entry. This is contrary to the django documentation that states "**Note that instantiating a model in no way touches your database**`; for that, you need to save().`" [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects). Here is an example:

```
In [4]: MyModel.objects.filter(email='test')
Out[4]: [<MyModel: MyModel object>]

In [5]: MyModel.objects.create(email='test')
Out[5]: <MyModel: MyModel object>

In [6]: MyModel.objects.filter(email='test')
Out[6]: [<MyModel: MyModel object>, <MyModel: MyModel object>]
```

As you see above, create() did indeed "touch the database." Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. `create` creates a record in the db. The doc passage you quote is referring to instantiating the model in memory:

```
my_instance = MyModel(email='test')
```

Comment: The verbiage of the docs and perhaps my ignorance has led me to great pain. :) I thought .create() _was_ how you instantiate an object! But now I understand the difference based on what you wrote and it's exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you!

Comment: In general, methods on the manager class (`objects`) work with the database.